# How to do exact (diacritic-sensitive) search in Adobe Reader X

Tags: adobe-reader

Using Adobe Reader X (v. 10.1.2), I tried to search for “Å” (A with ring above), but it keeps finding “A”, “Á”, “Â”, “Ä” etc., too. Even the full search (Ctrl+Shift+F) apparently lacks a possibility to request for exact search: I can tell it to be case sensitive and to search for full words only, but not to be sensitive to diacritic marks. This is rather nasty for texts where the diacritics make a big difference.

As a practical workaround, I can shift to Foxit Reader (where the search is automatically diacritic-sensitive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Edit` > `Preferences` > `Search` > `Ignore Diacritics and Accents` => Uncheck

Comment: Thanks, great! I was unable to find it on my own, since I’m using the Finnish version, and the word “Preferences” has oddly been localized using a word that means “Default values.”